# How do I call a class from another class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have Point() and LineSegment() as classes. Point() returns the x and y coordinates of the tuple point_a. How do I call Point() in a way that will allow me to use the x and y coordinates of two points to calculate the resulting line segment?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using classes instead of standard functions. Classes seem a bit overkill for what you need

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Then you can do the math within the LineSegment class.

```
class Point():
  <insert code here>

class LineSegment():
   def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
      self.first_point = Point(x1, y1)
      self.second_point = Point(x2, y2)
      < do something here >
```

Alternatively, you could pass two Point objects to the LineSegment class.

```
class LineSegment():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
       self.first_point = p1
       self.second_point = p2
          < do something here >
```

Where p1 might be Point(0, 0) or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! For the second option, how would I access the coordinates from the points? Would it be something like self.p1.x?

Comment: self.first_point.x, but yup! Just make sure the `Point` class has an attribute called x, which I'm sure it does.